# Export MapQuest map as image in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, mapping, mapquest

How would one export a MapQuest map as an image in response to a button click in an ASP.NET page. Unfortunately, the MapQuest API does not support this. How might this this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

The MapQuest Static Maps API enabled one to create the image:

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/static-maps-ws

Still need to figure out how to save the image in response to a button click.

Any other ideas?